# Python class to select features from pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm writing a wrapper class around a specific data set that will be represented as a pandas data frame. There are about 15 columns. I want the user to be able to select the columns they want at class construction time. Each column is constructed by a call to a method in the class, i.e. 
`def calculate_feature1():`. I'm considering making a boolean constructor param for each column, but I wonder if there is a better pattern.

```
class MyCoolDFWrapper:

    def __init__(include_feature_1=True, include_feature_2=True, etc ...)

    def calc_feature_1():
        pass

    ...

    def calc_feature_n():
        pass

    def get_data(self):
        return self.df[ " go calculate list of features they wanted to include " ]
```

Can this be improved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pure keyword arguments like this one:

```
def my_function(arg1, **kwargs)
```

Any argument you pass into my_function will be placed in the dictionary kwargs. You can view the content of the dictionary within the function at runtime.

So, you can give it the 15 Boolean arguments you wanted, or just an array of integers that contains the columns you want and based on that you can call your functions. But the question I would have is, do you really need 15 functions to calculate the features?